# How to make a restart command in discord.py in linux? even if it needs another files like shell or something

Tags: linux, ubuntu, discord, discord.py, restart

How to make a restart command in discord.py in Linux? even if it needs another files like shell or something? Im in Linux so please give me examples in Linux.

and I've tried

```
bot.logout(), bot.close()
```

and it just shutdown the bot I want an command that restarts the bot not shut it down

**Note:** I'm using Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to programatically restart your script.

This can be done by using

```
import os
os.execv("/usr/bin/python", ["python"] + ["/etc/discord_bot/bot.py"])
```

---

`"/usr/bin/python"` has to be the directory of your python binary. This could also be something like `"/usr/bin/python3.6"`

`["/etc/discord_bot/bot.py"]` has to be the **absolute** path to the main-file of your bot.

Comment: I want the best way to do restart command, please.